# Swift - Type of variable returned from DispatchTime.now()

Tags: swift, types, grand-central-dispatch, var

If I need to save the value of DispatchTime.now() to access it outside of the function in which it was called, what is the variable type?

Edit: the variable type is DispatchTime but I see no way to save that value as a variable so I can pass it along to another view controller in prepare(for segue) or use it across functions.

`var t = DispatchTime` [Expected member name or constructor call after type name]

`var t = DispatchTime()` [missing argument for parameter 'uptimeNanoseconds' in call]

`var t = DispatchTime.self` (no error, but when later trying t = DispatchTime.now() ['Cannot assign value of type 'DispatchTime' to type 'DispatchTime.Type'])

Comment: DipatchTime will be variable type.

Comment: Option click a variable in Xcode to see its inferred time. Command click a type/method/function/property to see its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `DispatchTime` as a variable. However if you need to store it somewhere outside the app's memory (some cache etc) you should take a look at this property of `DispatchTime`:

```
public let rawValue: dispatch_time_t
```

This is it's raw value in nanoseconds. From documentation (https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatch_time_t) you can see that it's of type UInt64. And to make everything even better, you can initialize `DispatchTime` with this method:

```
DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: <UInt64>)
```

That way you can store the raw value of your `DispatchTime` anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this, but no longer using DispatchTime in my project.

Can set the variable like this:
`var t = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 0)`

And then later fill the variable with the current time: `t = DispatchTime.now()`

This method was not giving me a correct number of seconds when trying to use:

```
let nanoTime = endingTime.uptimeNanoseconds - startTime.uptimeNanoseconds
let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
```

I've instead gone back to using CFAbsoluteTime() variables and setting their value to CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() upon start and stop.

That way `totalTime = endTime - startTime` gives me the correct number of seconds

Comment: Hey, I tried to delete this question but it warned me not to... What's the best course of action when you've written a bad question? I thought I'd leave an answer to explain my thinking but that has proved unpopular as well. I'd delete the question if I could as I don't see the value here for future readers.

Comment: It wasn't a bad question at all.